Identify this gay courtship scene from early 20th century period drama (1970sish?)
As an out bi man I sometimes try to identify pre-awareness moments. Stuff I noted and remembered about same-sex things from that might have hinted at future identity. 
One of those things is what I believe is a very old memory of a period drama caught on tv. I must have been in my early to mid teens which means we're talking about 25 years ago. I have no memory of the film as a whole, only this one scene.
The setting is a room or hall in a grand house. Aristocratic, presumably. 
A man is sitting at a piano. Another man comes into the room. The first man starts tentatively tapping out what I'll call the 'Papageno call-and-response theme' from Mozart's The Magic Flute: Pa-pa-pa-pa... The other man looks up. He makes his way to the piano and 'responds' by tapping out Papagena's part: Pa-pa-pa-pa... 
Going on the theme of the film/scene and the time of the memory I would date it no earlier than the 60s and no later than the 80s, probably 70s. As for the time period of the setting, the idea of it being Edwardian is somehow stuck in my mind but there is no particular reason it couldn't be 19th century just as well. British? Maybe Central European? 
